# Javascript preload callback

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I know very little javascript.
I need a basic preloader to load some heavy images from my website, here is the script that I found :

```
<div class="hidden">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
                    var images = new Array()
                    function preload() {
                        for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                            images[i] = new Image()
                            images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                        }
                    }
                    preload(
                        "img/artistes/01/01.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/02.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/03.png",
                        "img/artistes/01/04.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/05.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/06.png",
                        "img/artistes/01/07.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/08.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/09.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/10.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/11.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/12.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/13.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/14.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/15.png",
                        "img/artistes/01/16.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/thumbs/01.jpg",
                        "img/artistes/01/thumbs/02.jpg"
                    )
                //--><!]]>
            </script>
        </div>
```

What I would like to know if their is a way to simply remove this div once all of these images are loaded ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What div, the script tag doesn't really have anything to do with the div, you could place that script in the head section if that floats your boat !

Comment: What object is Image? Does it have a callback for completion? If so you could use that to check if numCompletions == numImages & then hide the div

Comment: The point would be to remove the hidden div once all images are preloaded.
I'll add that to the header tag, does make more sense. I'm still testing this out

Comment: i would recommend to use a library like mootools, you would then have a complete event that you can use to achieve whatever you want after the images are loaded ! (http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets#Asset:Asset-images)

Comment: Thanks for the mootools link, problem is I already have a jQuery library running, I really would like to avoid adding another one. But I'll keep this in favs for a next time !

Comment: But why would you need to remove or hide anything, the images are only loaded into the cache by javascript, they are never shown on the screen or put into that div element ?

Comment: The `<div>` appears to be intended to "hide" the `<script>`.  It is completely unnecessary, so the direct answer to your question is that you should leave the `<div>` out in the first place. Just include the `<script>`, and add `var i;` as the first line of the "preload" function.

Comment: Oh, also, change `preload.arguments` to just `arguments`.  And don't take any other scripts from wherever you found this one :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For jQuery you can use this code in head of the page,

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

preload([
    "img/artistes/01/01.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/02.jpg",             
    "img/artistes/01/03.png",   
    "img/artistes/01/04.jpg",    
    "img/artistes/01/05.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/06.png",
    "img/artistes/01/07.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/08.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/09.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/10.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/11.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/12.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/13.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/14.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/15.png",
    "img/artistes/01/16.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/thumbs/01.jpg",
    "img/artistes/01/thumbs/02.jpg"
]);
```

Note: you dont need to hide or remove anything, this is not visible to anyone.